# graph of multiple y axes in plotly

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I have 3 sets of comparison data(y axes) which needs to be plotted against a target source values. I'm comparing exports, gdp, standard of living values of different countries against a target countries values for different years. But values of each category are haphazard i.e exports in millions of dollars, gdp in percentage and standard of living scale of 1 to 10. Moreover I have years value for comparison as well.

What I want to see is over the years how different parameters for each country over different years vary against the target country parameters. All of this plotted in one graph in plotly.
I can plot multiple y axes in plotly, but the scale doesn't match.

Has anyone any suggestions how to fit all the comparison in one layout. Maybe this is more of a graphing suggestion needed rather than help in plotly? Any ideas how to squeeze all in one graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure, I work for Plotly.

Here's my shot at summarizing your problem in general, you've got 4 dimensions for each country (year, exports, gdp, standard of living).

You might be able to use either or both of these solutions:

- visualize this in two dimensions using x-value, y-value, marker-size, and marker-line-size (a bubble chart in 2d)
- visualize this in three dimensions using x-value, y-value, z-value, and marker-size

I'll leave a link to a notebook in the comments, but since it's not a very permanent link, I won't include it in the answer here.

Comment: Here's that nb: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/theengineear/6f9e17e5197a8ec153a5